# How to read a string with fmt.Scan after using bufio for reading a line in Go?

Tags: go

I read a line with `bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)`, then I read a string with `fmt.Scanf`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    )

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    
    var str string
    inp, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &str)
    
    fmt.Println(inp)
    fmt.Printf(str)
}
```

**Input:**

```
This is a sentence.
John
```

I expect the output to be like above, but it isn't.
**Output:**

```
This is a sentence.
```

actually `fmt.Scanf("%s", &str)` doesn't work.
What is the problem? and How can I fix it?

Comment: Actually, i reproduced the code and it works as expected.

Comment: please show here your reproduced code as an answer.

Comment: You miss the new line in the end, so that the John string sticks to the next thing in stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reader.ReadString(delim) reads everything up to the delim, including the delimiter. So, it adds \n between two inputs. fmt.Printf(str) does not have \n in the end, so the second output sticks to the next thing printed to stdout.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    var str string
    inp, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &str)

    fmt.Println(inp)
    fmt.Printf(str)
}
```

Input:

```
some line
John
```

Output:

```
some line

John
```

Below is the code that runs as you want it to.

```
   package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    var str string
    inp, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &str)

    fmt.Print(inp)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", str)
}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work correctly.
please try it on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_golang_online.php

Comment: I guess there is a bug with this playground. Perhaps, it does not read the second input. If you run it in terminal on your machine, it would work. Idk

Comment: Please refrain from posting screenshots of text. You could as well copied and pasted all the relevant text from the output in a block delimited by three consecutive backtick characters: ```